# sort blocks of texts in perl

Tags: regex, perl, sed, grep

I have a file that looks like:

```
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section1
 sub section2
SECTION2 id name  
 sub section3
 sub section4
 sub section6
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section7
 sub section8
SECTION3 id name  
 sub section9
 sub section10
 sub section11
 sub section12
SECTION2 id name  
 sub section13
 sub section14
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section15
 sub section16
SECTION3 id name  
 sub section17
 sub section18
```

I need to sort this file section wise. The only thing I know is that I have 'SECTION1', 'SECTION2' AND 'SECTION3'. 
Expected output after sorting is:

```
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section1
 sub section2
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section7
 sub section8
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section15
 sub section16
SECTION2 id name  
 sub section3
 sub section4
 sub section6
SECTION2 id name  
 sub section13
 sub section14
SECTION3 id name  
 sub section9
 sub section10
 sub section11
 sub section12
SECTION3 id name  
 sub section17
 sub section18
```

Is there any easy way to do this in perl or using the utilities like grep,sed etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more way using `perl`:

Assuming `infile` has the content of the question and following content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use sort qw/stable/;

my ($section, @section);

while ( <> ) { 

    ## Save text if first line or when line doesn't begin with 'SECTION' word.
    if ( $. == 1 || $_ !~ m/\ASECTION\d+/ ) { 
        $section .= $_; 
        next unless eof;
    }   

    ## Save the text and the number of section.
    if ( $section =~ m/\ASECTION(\d+)/ ) { 
        push @section, [ $1, $section ];
        $section = q||;
    }   

    ## Begin to save next section.
    $section .= $_; 
}

## Print them sorted by section number.
for ( sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @section ) { 
    printf qq|%s|, $_->[1];
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

With following output:

```
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section1
 sub section2
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section7
 sub section8
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section15
 sub section16
SECTION2 id name  
 sub section3
 sub section4
 sub section6
SECTION2 id name  
 sub section13
 sub section14
SECTION3 id name  
 sub section9
 sub section10
 sub section11
 sub section12
SECTION3 id name  
 sub section17
 sub section18
```

Comment: How did you sort the subsections?

Comment: @TLP: I save all section text in `$section` and insert it in an array with the number of the section. I don't sort subsections, they are output inside each section in same order.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that when I tested your code. For some reason, I just assumed they were unsorted, in which case my answer might be overkill. But hey, it was a fun exercise. :)

Comment: Note that if the output records need to be in the same order as the input (for all records with the same section number) you must add `use sort 'stable'` to achieve this. Otherwise the standard sort doesn't provide a stable sort algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like something that needs a special sort. Perl's default sort cannot properly sort strings with numbers, so we need to extract the numbers before we sort. In case of big data sets, I optimized it with a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

The basic gist of it is to extract first the section number, then the subsection number, and sort first on section number, and in case of a tie, sort on sub section number. Only the first number in the subsection is taken into consideration, and so it assumes that those lines are already sorted.

To use it on a file, simply change `<DATA>` to `<>`, then run:

```
perl script.pl inputfile > outputfile
```

**Code:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;           # read entire file
my $data = <DATA>;  # slurp input file into scalar
my @records = split /(?=^SECTION)/m, $data;  # split into records
my @sorted =    map  {  $_->[0] }
                sort {  $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] ||
                        $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] }  
                map   { getnum($_) } @records;   # Schwartzian transform sort
print @sorted;

sub getnum {    # extract section and subsection numbers
    my ($sec) = $_[0] =~ /SECTION(\d+)/;
    my ($sub) = $_[0] =~ /\n.*?(\d+)/;
    return [ $_[0], $sec, $sub ];    # return anonymous array
}

__DATA__
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section1
 sub section2
SECTION2 id name  
 sub section3
 sub section4
 sub section6
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section7
 sub section8
SECTION3 id name  
 sub section9
 sub section10
 sub section11
 sub section12
SECTION2 id name  
 sub section13
 sub section14
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section15
 sub section16
SECTION3 id name  
 sub section17
 sub section18
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data;
{   # limit change to $/ to this scope
    local $/ = "SECTION";
    @data = map {chomp; $_ || ()} <DATA>;   
}

{   # limit change to 'warnings' to this scope
    no warnings 'numeric';
    print "SECTION$_" for sort {$a <=> $b} @data;
}
```

This would preserve the individual sections.

Or from the command line:

```
perl -F/SECTION/ -0ane "print qq{SECTION$_} for grep $_, sort {$a <=> $b} @F" o33.txt
```

Comment: You get an extra space in your output due to using `-0` instead of `-0777`. I experimented with your one-liner and came up with this: `perl "-F/(?<=SECTION)/" -0777 -lane "print for sort {$a <=> $b} @F;"  sec.txt`. It sort of breaks the rules a bit, like yours did, in the sense that `SECTION` is placed last in the records, and by coincidence the first "blank" line floats to the top because `SECTION` evaluates to 0. A bit ugly, but fun.

Comment: @TLP Well, I just learned something new - surrounding the -F switch with quotes when using a complex regexp to split on, I believe. Nice use of the non capturing look behind feature. In mine, I have to reinsert SECTION into my print statement.

Comment: You can also just do `-F"(?<=SECTION)"`, which now that I think about it, is simpler. Keeping `SECTION` will break the implicit numerical conversion, so that was not an option when golfing.

Comment: @TLP The following also worked - I hadn't thought of trying it until after seeing your solution. And I didn't know if the \K symbol, (or whatever is the correct term), would preserve the SECTION text that the text was splitting on. `perl -F/SECTION\K/ -0777 -ane "print for sort {$a <=> $b} @F;"`

Comment: Yes, `\K` works about the same as the look-behind assertion. You know what they say, TIMTOWTDI: `perl -e "$/ = 'SECTION'; print for sort {$a <=> $b} <>;"`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/\nSECTION/!s/\n/\x00/;ta;s/n\([0-9][\x00\n]\|$\)/n0\1/g;P;D' file |
sort |
sed 's/\x00/\n/g;s/n0/n/g'
```

Explanation:

- Join `SECTIONs` and `sub sections` into single lines. `:a;$!N;/\nSECTION/!s/\n/\x00/;ta`
- Prepend `0`'s to `sub sections`. `s/n\([0-9][\x00\n]\|$\)/n0\1/g`
- Print each line then delete it. `P;D`
- Sort the piped output. `sort`
- Deconstruct the sorted output. `sed 's/\x00/\n/g;s/n0/n/g'`

Answer (score 1):

This is done very simply by accumulating the records in three sparate lists according to the section label.

This program uses a hash to do this, and builds complete sections by appending each line from the file to the most recent record. If the line is the beginning of a new section another empty record is added to the list before the line is appended.

Displaying the results is simply a matter of printing all elements of the lists in order of their section labels.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'sections.txt' or die $!;

my %sections;
my $current_list;

while (<$fh>) {
  if (/^(SECTION[123])/) {
    $current_list = $sections{$1} //= [];
    push @$current_list, '';
  }
  $current_list->[-1] .= $_ if $current_list;
}

for my $name (sort keys %sections) {
  print for @{ $sections{$name} };
}
```

**output**

```
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section1
 sub section2
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section7
 sub section8
SECTION1 id name  
 sub section15
 sub section16
SECTION2 id name  
 sub section3
 sub section4
 sub section6
SECTION2 id name  
 sub section13
 sub section14
SECTION3 id name  
 sub section9
 sub section10
 sub section11
 sub section12
SECTION3 id name  
 sub section17
 sub section18
```

Comment: This solution will break when the sections reach 4. The sort will break at 10.

Comment: @TLP: arbitrarily changing the question will break any solution.

Comment: There's nothing arbitrary about my comment. It's fully reasonable to assume that the number of sections can exceed 3, and your solution is hard coded to not work with any other numbers in two different ways.

Comment: @TLP: From the question, *The only thing I know is that I have 'SECTION1', 'SECTION2' AND 'SECTION3'*. It seems we can rely on that, if nothing else.

Comment: You're right, that sentence does make it sound as though those are the only keywords expected. I think it would be appropriate to point out this limitation in your answer, though.